# Pandas to compare the column (A) with other column (B) and return the unique values which is present in Column (A)

Tags: excel, performance, python-3.x, pandas, ipython

I am facing an issue while comparing the two column with very data contains approximate 5 to 6 lacks of cells. And I used **countif** formula to check the existence of value in Column A with Column B. However, it is taking huge time to calculate and I stopped the using excel for that task. And I am finding n alternative way of doing this in Pandas.

Is it is possible to find the list of unique values in Column A by comparing Column B. Please suggest.

Column A: 585256

Column B: 556245

[image]

Comment: Sorry can you post a representative sample data and code to show your df and desired result, there is `unique()` which will give you all unique values and you can use `isin()` to test for membership

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey it is quiet easy by using the default python data structure that is sets.

Below is the simple snippet which returns the set difference.

```
def get_difference(file_1, file_2):
    data_1 = set(open(file_1, encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines())
    data_2 = set(open(file_2, encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines())
    return data_1 - data_2
```

I have checked the performance with the data around 500000 lines. And script produced result with in 2 secs.